# Using bgl to build search tree with dfs

Tags: c++, boost

I would like to create a search tree of a graph using dfs algorithm. I get compilation errors over and over my code is like that (the compilation error is so long that I do not paste it):

```
typedef adjacency_list <vecS, vecS, undirectedS> Graph;   
typedef graph_traits <Graph>::edge_descriptor Edge;
typedef graph_traits <Graph>::vertex_descriptor Vertex;

typedef pair<int, int> E;
vector<E> edges;

Graph g(edges.begin(), edges.end(), n);

vector<Vertex> p(n);
Vertex s = vertex(0,g);

breadth_first_search(g, s, visitor(record_predecessors(&p[0], on_tree_edge())));
```

Part of error:

```
instantiated from here
/usr/include/boost/graph/breadth_first_search.hpp:39:7: error: ‘struct boost::predecessor_recorder<long unsigned int*, boost::on_tree_edge>’ has no member named ‘initialize_vertex’
/usr/include/boost/graph/breadth_first_search.hpp:40:7: error: ‘struct boost::predecessor_recorder<long unsigned int*, boost::on_tree_edge>’ has no member named ‘discover_vertex’
/usr/include/boost/graph/breadth_first_search.hpp:41:7: error: ‘struct boost::predecessor_recorder<long unsigned int*, boost::on_tree_edge>’ has no member named ‘examine_vertex’
/usr/include/boost/graph/breadth_first_search.hpp:42:7: error: ‘struct boost::predecessor_recorder<long unsigned int*, boost::on_tree_edge>’ has no member named ‘examine_edge’
/usr/include/boost/graph/breadth_first_search.hpp:43:7: error: ‘struct boost::predecessor_recorder<long unsigned int*, boost::on_tree_edge>’ has no member named ‘tree_edge’
/usr/include/boost/graph/breadth_first_search.hpp:44:7: error: ‘struct boost::predecessor_recorder<long unsigned int*, boost::on_tree_edge>’ has no member named ‘non_tree_edge’
/usr/include/boost/graph/breadth_first_search.hpp:45:7: error: ‘struct boost::predecessor_recorder<long unsigned int*, boost::on_tree_edge>’ has no member named ‘gray_target’
/usr/include/boost/graph/breadth_first_search.hpp:46:7: error: ‘struct boost::predecessor_recorder<long unsigned int*, boost::on_tree_edge>’ has no member named ‘black_target’
/usr/include/boost/graph/breadth_first_search.hpp:47:7: error: ‘struct boost::predecessor_recorder<long unsigned int*, boost::on_tree_edge>’ has no member named ‘finish_vertex’
make: *** [file] Error 1
```

Comment: What sort of compilation error ?

Comment: Please post whole code, some typedefs and variables are missing

Comment: ok I edited it. Generaly remaing things are form boost.  (I use boost namespace)

Comment: Your title and post says DFS but your code uses BFS. I suggested an edit but it was rejected by the community. If you meant BFS but misspelled it, you may want to edit your post, so people don't end up here when googling DFS.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`breadth_first_search` expects a `BFSVisitor`. `record_predecessors` returns an `EventVisitor`. You need to use `make_bfs_visitor` in order to make it work.

```
breadth_first_search(g, s, visitor(make_bfs_visitor(record_predecessors(&p[0], on_tree_edge()))));
```